# When I rotate legs they become very deformed, arms are similar shape but does not do this

Tags: pose-mode

https://pasteall.org/blend/11de9ffda02344cc83bad2380e3c42f8
Im trying to rotate the legs to create a running animation but when I do the legs become very deformed. When[image] I rotate the arms it does not do this, how can I fix it?

[[image: Resting position, shaped how I want it to vs. rotated for running position but deformed ][1]]

Comment: hello, please share your file (copy paste the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/11de9ffda02344cc83bad2380e3c42f8 Thanks, couldnt figure out how to add files

Comment: If you want to bend the arms and legs you need to add a few more edge loops (Ctrl+R in Edit mode) that work as elbows and knees.

Answer (score 1):

You've scaled the armature (it is stretched on the Z axis), it deforms the parented object, so go into *Object* mode, select your armature and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *(Apply) > Scale*

Comment: That worked, thank you!